# Is there any way to write odata custom filter?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata, odatacontroller

We are facing the problem of odata filter which is related to date and time. Also, we want to filter data with some custom values.

Please let us know if any want to do same

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example? The OData protocol is pretty open, normally you can achieve this with the out-of-the-box functionality

Comment: Appreciate your reply,   When I filter with a date from UI grid date parameter sent to api like $filter: (StartTime ge 2018-06-13T13:00:00+00:00 and StartTime le 2018-06-14T12:59:59+00:00)  which is in UTC format . I want to convert UTC date into .ToLocalTime () in C#  to match records exist in a database.